# Compilation errors after re-installation

Tags: graphics, texlive, ubuntu, compilation-error

I re-installed my OS (Ubuntu 20.04) and Latex (package texlive-latex-extra), and I get compilation errors for my previously working documents.
The documents still work fine on Overleaf, but not on my machine. Most errors seem to stem from graphics.

Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode=true]
 {hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centerline{ \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{ {{Figs/DW_narrow_wide/potential}} } }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Error:
`` LaTeX Error: File ` {{Figs/DW_narrow_wide/potential}} ' not found. ``
Even though the file is clearly there and it worked before (and online).
I never quite understood why I had to use double braces around the file name, but even if I remove them and use one or no curly braces, it does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why all the extra `{}` in `h]{ {{Figs/DW_narrow_wide/potential}} }` ??? as you see in the error message they are taken as a literal part of the file name. It can never work with those braces. (or the space)

Comment: unrelated but `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}` it would be better to use utf-8 and delete this line, certainly any examples you post on this site will be utf-8 not latin9, as they will be converted to utf-8 as you paste in to the code block.

Comment: I've tried `\includegraphics{ {{example-image}} }` with TeX Live from 2012 up to 2023 and the error message is *always* the same, namely ``! LaTeX Error: File ` {{example-image}} ' not found.``

Comment: I don't know why I needed the braces for it to work before tbh. Why does it work on Overleaf with the braces then? If I remove the two braces around the file name as well as the latin9 line I still get the same error saying that the figure was not found.

Comment: did you remove the spaces as well

Comment: No, my bad, it works. I indeed had to remove the braces. I am super confused. I definitely had to use the braces before, I even got the tip from sites like this one. Thank you everyone. Is there maybe a scenario where there are special characters in the file names where one would need those braces?

Comment: there is no way it can have worked with double braces. (I did write that code:-)